# VSCodeでCSS等にカラーコード記述するとその色を示すアイコンが欲しい

Tags: css, vscode

VSCode使い例えばCSSにカラーコードを打ち込んだ場合
以下の画像のように「カラーコードの前にその色を示す四角形のアイコンが表示され、これを押すとカラーピッカーが出てくる」というシンプルな形式にしたいと思っています。以前Bracketsを使っておりデフォルトでこのような形式だったと思います。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ウェブサイトなどでVSCodeのお勧めの拡張機能を探してみると”Color Highlight”という拡張機能がよく紹介されています。
しかし、自分にとっては派手というか、見づらく感じます。カラーピッカーもどこを押してもカラーピッカーやカラーの情報等は出てきません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

それ以外に”VS Color Picker”、”Color Picker”等カラーコードの色を示してくれると思われる拡張機能を探してみたのですが軒並み効いてくれません。
「すべて外しデフォルトにしたらいいのでは？」と言ってくれる方もいましたので
カラーコードの色を示してくれる類の拡張子は全て外しました。
現在私のVSCodeに入っている拡張機能は以下が全てです。

**Docker

Eslint

Git Graph

Git History

GitLens

Highlight Matching Tag

HTMC CSS Support

HTML Hint

indent-rainbow

Insert Numbers

Japanese Language Pack for Visual Studio Code

Live Server

Monokai Dark Soda

Path Intellisense

PHP intelliSense

Polacolo-2020

Prettier-Code form

Remote-Containers

Remote-WSL

Tabnine - Code Faster

vscode-icon

zenkaku**

何かが邪魔しているのでしょうか？

カラーコード系の拡張機能は思いつく限りアンインストールしたつもりです。

で、現状はこのようにカラーコードが記号として表示されているだけです。
これはさすがに困ります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

この状態から上記した”VS Color Picker”、”Color Picker”をインストールしても全く効いてくれません。効いてくれるのは上の画像に上げた”Color Highlight”だけです。

設定がおかしいのでしょうか？　あるいは何らかの別の拡張機能が邪魔しているのでしょうか？　jsonファイル等で修正出来るようでしたら教えて下さい。

原因が全く思いつきません。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

設定→設定→「settings.jsonで編集」内で

```
"editor.colorDecorators": false,
```

となっていましたので　true　へ変更すると

```
 "editor.colorDecorators": true,
```

デフォルト状態に戻りました。無事解決しました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]